# The size of my given folder ($1) in bytes. (bash ubuntu)

Tags: bash

I need to find the total size of a given folder ($1) and i want to output it as $totalSize so that the following works. It has to be in bytes.

```
if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
    totalsize=$(....)
        echo "The total size of the given folder is $totalSize bytes"
else
    echo "$1 is not a directory..."
fi
```

Comment: Are you looking for `du -s`?

Comment: I've tried alot really. But i usually get what i think is the output in kilobytes. I'm really new to this and can't honestly type down all the stuff i've tried.

Comment: Also du -s gives me 885444, when the foldersize is 138.1 kiB

Comment: how do i use du -s on $1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the total size with :

```
#!/bin/bash

sizeko=$(du --max-depth=0 "$1" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
totalsize=$(( $sizeko * 1024 ))
echo $totalsize
```

The `du` outputs the result in kilobytes.

If you want it in bytes, juste calculate it (the size on disk will always be a multiple of 1024).

If you want the real size of the files in your dir rather than the space occupied on disk, add a `-b` to `du` :

```
#!/bin/bash

totalsize=$(du -b --max-depth=0 "$1" | sed 's/\([0-9]*\).*/\1/')
echo $totalsize
```

Comment: When i try this i get 188 as total size, the size should be at least 140 000 bytes.

Comment: The result is in kylobytes

Comment: But my question is how to get it in bytes

Comment: Sorry, i updated my answer. Why not just calculate it ?

Comment: If the size where to be in lets say 100 bytes or 10M bytes, will i still get it in K bytes?

Comment: Thank you :) i'm totaly new with this.